# A little is getting through all the same - I can't understand this

Tags: grammar

Source: http://news.yahoo.com/east-ukraine-city-dying-under-siege-180159011.html

> With gas reserves all but exhausted, even those willing to brave a drive out of the city for supplies struggle to refill their cars.
>   **A little is getting through all the same**, mainly from Russia. Pro-rebel online television station Luhansk-24 on Sunday carried a report about a consignment of medicinal supplies reaching the city from the southern Russian city of Saratov.

**A little is getting through**. Alright. I understand that it means not a lot of food supplies reaching the city. But how is **all the same** connected to that statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's used in the "anyway" kind of meaning, as in "some people manage to leave the city, but it's difficult (for them) to bring back supplies anyway".

Answer (score 0):

As Maciej said, it can be used in the sense of "anyway", but considering the tone of the passage, it might make more sense to interpret it as "despite all the difficulties" -- in spite of the fact that other conditions are staying the same, something (the thing of interest) is happening or being done.

You can interpret the second paragraph's opening sentence as: 

"**Despite these difficult conditions remaining unchanged, some supplies are being brought in**, most of which are from Russia."